# Error on post data to curl after submit data in database

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I want post data to payment gateway api after submit data into database but getting error and not redirecting to api url... if any one help it will be appreciate.anyone guide me whats wrong in code... Data submit in database but when i try to post this data to url i am getting error and not redirecting to payment gatway api..

include 'db-config.php';

```
$encdata="647569415339326A5A715930594B6530396D4C506B396E434561504D67334678316F514C36556A6F6278303869734F3173316F6C45725775374C357936684A6C6D6C5756752B566C674F46724A534A73686E464953773D3D";
//processPaymentResponse($encdata);
function encodedStringUCOGateWay($data){
    $key = '32423423';
    $realKey = substr($key, 0, 16);
    $padding = pkcs5_pad($data, 16);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    return strtoupper(bin2hex(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $realKey, $padding, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB))));
}

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize){
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function processPaymentResponse($msg){
    $val = $msg;
    $key = 'dfsffsd34234'; 
    $realKey = substr($key, 0, 16);
    $data = base64_decode(hex2bin($val));
    $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $realKey, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
    $decodedString = substr($data, 0, -$padding);  
    echo $decodedString;      
    /*  MERCHANT REF NO^UCO PAYMENT SOLUTION REF NO^AMOUNT^TXN STATUS@SELECTED PG REF NO|SELECTED CHANNEL|BANK REF NO|TXN STATUS AT PG
        123456^PG2220000000011^2500.00^SUCCESS@PG123456|EBNK|CBS1234|SUCCESS*/        
    $txnStatus = explode("@",$decodedString);
    $appPayStatus = explode("^",$txnStatus[0]);
    $payGateWayStatus = explode("|",$txnStatus[1]);
    $ausPayRef = $appPayStatus[0];
    $ausUCOPayRefNo = $appPayStatus[1];
    $paiedAmount = $appPayStatus[2];
    $payTxnStatus = $appPayStatus[3];
    $pgRefNo = $payGateWayStatus[0];
    $selectedChennel = $payGateWayStatus[1];
    $bankRefNo = $payGateWayStatus[2];
    $pgTxnStatus = $payGateWayStatus[3];
    $appNo = $_SESSION['app_no'];
    $candidateId = $_SESSION['app_id'];  
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['SNAME'];
    $email = $_POST['SEMAILID'];
    $father_name = $_POST['father_name'];
    $admission_number = $_POST['admission_number'];
    $roll_number = $_POST['SRN'];
    $mobile = $_POST['SMOBNO'];
    $mprn = $_POST['MPRN'];
    $mtamt = $_POST['MTAMT'];


    /*$sql = "INSERT INTO `tansaction`(`id`, `student_name`, `father_name`, `roll_number`, `admission_number`, `email`, `phone`, `mprn`, `mtamt`, `status`) VALUES (NULL , '$name', '$father_name' , '$roll_number' , '$admission_number' , '$email' , '$mobile' , '$mprn' , '$mtamt')";*/


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tansaction`(`student_name`, `father_name`, `roll_number`, `admission_number`, `email`, `phone`, `mprn`, `mtamt`) VALUES ( '$name', '$father_name' , '$roll_number' , '$admission_number' , '$email' , '$mobile' , '$mprn' , '$mtamt')";

     if($result = mysqli_query($conn , "$sql"))
     {

        $url = 'http://uatucoebanking.co.in/LocalBankAwayRetail/sgonHttpHandler.aspx?Action.FCIGATEWAY.ShoppingMall.Login=Y';
$fields = array(
    'SNAME' => urlencode($_POST['SNAME']),
    'SEMAILID' => urlencode($_POST['SEMAILID']),
    'father_name' => urlencode($_POST['father_name']),
    'company' => urlencode($_POST['admission_number']),
    'SRN' => urlencode($_POST['SRN']),
    'SMOBNO' => urlencode($_POST['SMOBNO']),
    'MPRN' => encodedStringUCOGateWay(urlencode($_POST['MPRN'])),
    'MTAMT' => encodedStringUCOGateWay(urlencode($_POST['MTAMT']))
);





//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&'); 
//$query_string = http_build_query($_POST);
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

     }

     else 
     {
     echo "error in query ";
     }

}
```

Edit: Error recieved on curl-call:
`(S(hi03ut553axfeiucxuusckev))/FileNotFound.htm?aspxerrorpath‌​=/LocalBankAwayRetai‌​l/sgonHttpHandler.as‌​px` getting this url error after domain.. when i try to post to api direct to form action its working but i want to post via another method because post data need encryption

Comment: Including all that code does not do much - include the ERROR, debug what curl is getting as computed input. I highly doubt your keys are as is so we can`t reproduce anything with this code - so its no minimal example at all. Sorry.

Comment: data is inserting in database when i try to post this data into api m getting error

Comment: Yes - so curl gives you an error. Debug what curl is getting as input, see what the output is and post this and the **exact error wording** - we cant reproduce the error with what is given, how should we be able to help? If the in-/output of curl holds sensible things (id/pw) mask them before posting.

Comment: (S(hi03ut553axfeiucxuusckev))/FileNotFound.htm?aspxerrorpath=/LocalBankAwayRetail/sgonHttpHandler.aspx    getting this url error after domain.. when i try to post to api direct to form action its working but i want to post via another method because post data need encryption..